# com.ironsource.sdk.controller.IronSourceWebView$JSInterface Unresolved class name

Tags: android, proguard, ironsource

I'm trying to integrate ironSource SDK, but unfortunaly I get `Unresolved class name` error on `com.ironsource.sdk.controller.IronSourceWebView$JSInterface` while trying to apply the code to ProGuard settings:

```
`-keepclassmembers class com.ironsource.sdk.controller.IronSourceWebView$JSInterface {
    public *;
}
-keepclassmembers class * implements android.os.Parcelable {
    public static final android.os.Parcelable$Creator *;
}
-keep public class com.google.android.gms.ads.** {
   public *;
}
-keep class com.ironsource.adapters.** { *;
}
-dontwarn com.ironsource.mediationsdk.**
-dontwarn com.ironsource.adapters.**
-keepattributes JavascriptInterface
-keepclassmembers class * {
    @android.webkit.JavascriptInterface <methods>;
}`
```

Any idea how to solve this issue?

Comment: I have the same problem...

Answer (score 0):

If your project uses WebView with JS, uncomment the following
and specify the fully qualified class name to the JavaScript interface

```
-keepclassmembers class com.ironsource.sdk.controller.IronSourceWebView$JSInterface {
    public *;

}
```

if not

```
    #-keepclassmembers class com.ironsource.sdk.controller.IronSourceWebView$JSInterface {
    #public *;

#}
```